# Exception : Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed

Tags: magento2

what is the replacement for below code within xml

> htmlClass

I am getting this **error** :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'htmlClass':The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.
```

this is the offending code:

```
  <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlClass="ticket-media product media">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="eventticketimage" template="Magenest_Ticket::catalog/product/images.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and also this:

```
   <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" htmlClass="ticket-page-title
page-title" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove **htmlClass="ticket-page-title**
form below code

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" htmlClass="ticket-page-title
page-title" remove="true"/>
```

as htmlClass not allowed in block or referenceBlock .

Answer (score 1):

There are only **two** allowed attributes for **reference blocks**

**#1 remove**

**#2 display**

Where the **container** has the following attributes

**#1 htmlClass**

**#2 htmlId**

**#3 htmlTag**

**#4 output**

**#5 as**

**#6 after**

**#7 before**

**#8 label**

**#9 name**

hence the **htmlClass** is not applicable for **referenceBlock**

DovDocs for reference [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref)